# Automatically recognising "doesn't work" and suggesting a better explanation

Tags: feature-request

When a poster asks a question, the words **doesn't work** make my blood boil.

Can we recognise these words and suggest to the poster that that post more information about how it 'doesn't work'. Along the lines of when an email client recognises the word *attachment* in your email but there is no attachment present.

Example here:

[set filepath from database in SSIS variable for logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15432836/set-filepath-from-database-in-ssis-variable-for-logging#comment21890163_15432836)

Comment: I see this has already been raised with a lot more practical suggestions.